# Template matching involving scale-, rotation- and shape-invariant transformation

Tags: multivariate-analysis, image-processing, procrustes-analysis

I am not sure whether this is the right place to ask this question, but any possible answer will help.

I want to apply some form of template matching on these set of pictures.

This is the template picture:

[image]

This is the picture in which I want to search for the template picture and the black rectangle, frame the template shapes which should be identified within the picture:

[image]

I have done all the coding for this in Matlab and I have managed to apply template matching algorithms, sift(scale invariant feature transform), histogram based matching, and also, I have tried to apply a variation of expectation maximization on the blue and red areas.

The problem, as you can see from the images, is that the areas where you can identify the template image are totally deformed. So I should apply some template matching algorithms which should be invariant to scaling, rotation and partial deformation of the template image.

Can you please recommend me some computer vision algorithms or techniques for this type of transform which are invariant to scaling, rotation and partial deformation of the template image shape?

Comment: I can put pictures in the post if you agree to CC by-sa them.

Comment: yes, if you can attach those pictures, I would be grateful.

Comment: One of the most popular shape-comparison techniques is Procrustes analysis. It is invariant in shift, scale and rotation. It's not invariant to deformation, rather, degree of deformation (not sameness of forms) is what the analysis tells about.